# Nginx with docker: Reverse Proxy doesn't work

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I recently want to set a reverse proxy server. I pulled a nginx docker image and I ran the docker container using this command:

```
docker run -d --name ngtest -p 4080:80 nginx
```

Then I updated the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf like below:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server{
        listen 80;
        location /nexus/ {
            proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.30:8081/;
        }
    }
}
```

The container works after restarted, when I tried to open page
http://192.168.0.30:4080, I got the default Nginx page.

However when I tried this url: http://192.168.0.30:4080/nexus, I got a 404 page with errors.

From the log, it looks that the nginx didn't forward the url to the page I set in nginx.conf, instead it tried to look the page in the local directory:

```
2020/03/11 16:10:34 [error] 6#6: *251 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/nexus" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.153, server: localhost, request: "GET /nexus HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.30:4080"
192.168.0.153 - - [11/Mar/2020:16:10:34 +0000] "GET /nexus HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Is there anything wrong in my steps?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even with your updated config you are still doing:

> include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

Which is loading `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` which will be the default server in the event no server name is provided based on the rules of determining the server to use if server name not found.

You should do something like:

Save to a config file your server definition of:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    location /nexus/ {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.30:8081/;
    }
}
```

Then run

`docker run -d -p 4080:80 -v (path_to_your_config):/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx`

This will replace the default config with yours. Then if you need to make changes you just make them and restart the container.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error somewhere in the nginx or in the dependencies. For my case it was to do with the SSL certificate for example `example.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE` and `example.com_ssl_certificate` had extra lines in the bundle that I had created. Also check the `example.com_private_key` file if it's still to do with the SSL.

To check the error log, run the following command for details:
`docker-compose logs -f`